# Why TAGS file is loaded/visited automatically if it exists in project root directory?

Tags: ctags

If the root of the project has a `TAGS` file, and I load/visit a file `FOO` from this dir into a freshly started Emacs, Emacs loads/visits two files, and the buffer list shows `FOO` and `TAGS`.

I also get a message `Starting a new list of tags tables`.

Is this a normal behavior?

Edit: this seems to happen when `projectile-mode` is enabled. Is this related?

Comment: It's related, yes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projectile does do this. See `projectile-find-file-hook-function`:

https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/blob/master/projectile.el#L4760-L4773

Comment: Thank you. Is visiting the TAGS file necessary for Projectile to be able to work with it? It clutters the buffer list, which is not useful.  I searched `customize-group` for Projectile's customization for TAGS auto-loading behavior, and didn't find any.

Comment: It's considered a convenience. There's no customization option, AFAIK, but you can ask for one on Projectile's issue tracker.